# Check for letter in text file python

Tags: file, python-3.x

I need to count the number of vowels in a text file given to me (with python program) and return the number. For whatever reason when I run the program the file returns 0 vowels even though the count variable is supposed to increase by one each time it loops and finds a vowel.

```
def numVowels(file):
    count = 0
    opened_file = open(file)
    content = opened_file.readlines()
    for char in content:
        if char.lower() in 'aeiou':
            count += 1
    return(count)
```

I'm not sure if that is because I am working with a text file, but usually I am able to do this without an issue. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`readlines()` returns a list of lines from the file so `for char in content:` means `char` is a line of text in the file which isn't what you are looking for.
You can `read()` the whole file into memory or iterate through the file line by line and then iterate through the line character at at time:

```
def numVowels(file):
    count = 0
    with open(file) as opened_file:
        for content in opened_file:
            for char in content:
                if char.lower() in 'aeiou':
                    count += 1
    return count
```

You can sum a generator of 1's to produce the same value:

```
def numVowels(file):
    with open(file) as f:
        return sum(1 for content in f for char in content if char.lower() in 'aeiou')
```

Comment: Thank you so much. I didn't realize it returned a list of lines!